# Вирусы на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Вчера на сайте в определенное время стали появляться новые включения в html код страницы примерно такого рода:

```
<script src="url чужого сайта(http://acl.interjs.net/.....)"></script>
```

и попытки перенаправить на этот сайт посетителя.
через какое-то время всё это прекратилось само собой. Что это могло быть? В коде php скрипта ничего нового нет, проверка сайта на вирусы тоже показала, что всё чисто.
Антивирус блокировал это перенаправление как подозрительную активность.

Comment: А как обстоит дело с БД? Про это вы не упомянули. Как очень примитивный пример, но если в поле с типом TEXT будет строка

    "<script>alert('Ups');</script>";

которую выводить без экранирования, то она нормальненько себе отработает.

Comment: В БД тоже всё чисто.

Comment: Joomla 1.5?

Comment: 1. Сменить пароль к FTP

2. Не хранить пароли в программах для подключения к FTP

Comment: Нет, самописный сайт с нуля, но всё, что можно, для защиты от xss-атак и sql-инъекций, вроде, сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если точно нет в коде, значит сидит у тебя на компе и уже подключился ко всему трафику в нете, из этого совет, проверь полностью комп на вирусы(у тебя же винда? Угадал?!)

Эта заразная штука, иногда лечится только переустановкой винды т.к. затирает какие-то файлы. У меня раз было, с того момента ушел в мир Unix, и ни в чем себе не отказываю теперь.

Comment: Переустановка винды как лечение - это, мягко скажем, радикально. В большинстве случаев можно обойтись без этого.

Comment: В данном случае это был единственный вариант, т.к. вирус покосил много системных файлов + прописался в кучу сервисов, и да замена этих файлов на новые никак не помогла.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблемы не у вас, а у хостера. Сталкивался с таким однажды, у них все индексные файлы для всех пользователей перезаписались, сказали что их взломали и так нагадили. Кстати все изменения успели записаться в резервную копию, так что восстанавливать пришлось с домашнего.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы, пока на своем компьютере нашла вирус другим антивирусом. Надеюсь, что дело было только в нем.

Answer (score 1):

Такое могут спокойно сделать и плагины в браузере (либо userscript). Как вариант проверить установленные дополнения в браузер.